# does iostream.h gets compiled?

Tags: c++, compilation

I have a very basic question.

Lets take the following code snippet:

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
   std::cout<<"Hello world \n";
}
```

In the above program, does 'iostream' gets compiled?

If it compiles, isn't it a overhead?

Because anyways we are not going to change anything in iostream, but it gets compiled everytime :-/

Please help me understand this.

Comment: Your title has .h, `iostream` has no `.h`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The include basically pastes the content of `<iostream>` in your source file, so you could say it gets compiled.

> If it compiles, isn't it a overhead?

It takes longer, but you need the include because you use `std::cout`. This is one of the reasons why you should only include what you need and use declarations instead wherever possible.

What you can do is look into precompiled headers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes every header that is included will be compiled.

Yes it is overhead which is why some compilers have something called precompiled headers.

Remember that C++ is build on C which is quite an old language and this is one of the areas it shows.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly: You can't really 'compile' headers to object files/executables - they only contain type and other information for the compiler to produce *correct* code. You can, however, include the files and make the compiler parse them to obtain info. Yes, it may be a very small overhead, but really, you have to include it.